# Error when purchasing auto-renewable subscriptions (not supported in your storefront)

Tags: ipad, app-store, in-app-purchase

I am trying to test auto-renewable subscriptions in the sandbox environment.
I've defined an auto renewable product in iTunes connect and my app successfully gets its details using the store kit.
However I get an error after I confirm the purchasing.

**Subscriptions Not Supported.
Automatically renewing subscriptions are not supported in your storefront at this time.
Environment: Sandbox**

When I change my code to purchase a non consumable product instead of the auto-renewable product the purchase ends OK.(I have the product ID hard coded in my test code)

Are there any difference in the way I should implement the purchasing of non-consumable and auto-renewable subscriptions?

Are you aware of any sample code for auto renewable subscriptions? especially for the next steps of restoring subscriptions from the application (in my case I don't have to download any content from a server. Just have to check if a user has an active subscription)

I use iPad2 with ios 4.3.3. The application runs from Xcode 4.0.2

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: It looks like there are stores that still does not support auto-renewable subscriptions. I don't have the list of countries without this feature. When you develop a global app you should consider this.